# Angular Shorthand on $scope for saving data

Tags: angularjs

is there any shorthand for something like this?

```
 var data = 
 {
    name: $scope.admin.name,
    email: $scope.admin.email,
    roles: $scope.admin.roles
 };
```

Usually after i query and input to model i can just use like this:

```
 $scope.admin = {
     name: value1,
     email: value2,
     roles: value3
 }
```

Edited:
My exact question inside var data how can i make it more simple like above without keep typing "$scope.admin".

Thanks

Comment: You're asking to access javascript values without using `this`. The best you can do is use `controller as` syntax and use `self` or `this`.

Comment: Question is unclear, what is your problem and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Desty I update my question above. hope it make it more clear what i trying to achieve

Comment: @ashish self and this * is it angular way?

Comment: @sstarlight If you're using `controller as` syntax then you need to use `self` or `this`, and `controller as` syntax is regarded as a best practice. :)

Comment: @ashish sorry for late reply. okay will do that! thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want a deep copy with `angular.copy()`, but just want to type less signs in code, you can do

```
var x = $scope.admin;
var data = 
{
    name: x.name,
    email: x.email,
    roles: x.roles
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy all the properties, use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
angular.copy($scope.admin, $scope.user)
```

---

If you need to pick a *subset* of properties, a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) might be useful. You would use the `pick` function:

```
$scope.admin = {
    firstname: 'John',
    name: 'Doe',
    email: 'john@mycompany.com',
    roles: ['sysadmin']
};

$scope.user = _.pick($scope.admin, ['name', 'email', 'roles']);

// -> {name: 'Doe', email: 'john@mycompany.com', roles: ['sysadmin']}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. thats what i'm looking for. but i'm not using lodash. is there any angular way? to save that $scope.admin to a var so i can post it.

Comment: Well, this is more a *js* problem than an angular one. You could do that in plain js though, but it would not be a oneliner.

Comment: By the way, if you want to copy *all* the properties of the source object, have a look at the `angular.copy` function